# Change url from domain.com/user/amp/username to domain.com/username in codeignator

Tags: codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

Change url from domain.com/user/amp/username to domain.com/username

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] =  FALSE;
$route['/(.*)'] = "user/amp/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .htaccess file on your project root folder. File content like this;

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^user/amp/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['username'] = 'user/amp/username';
```